# What is this Scrapy error: ReactorNotRestartable?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I do not understand why my spider wont run. I tested the css selector separately, so I do not think it is the parsing method.

Traceback message:
ReactorNotRestartable:

```
class espn_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fsu2021_spider"
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = "https://www.espn.com/college-football/team/_/id/52"
        for url in urls: 
            yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse_front)
    def parse(self, response):
        schedule_link = response.css('div.global-nav-container li > a::attr(href)')
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(espn_spider)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> urls = "https://www.espn.com/college-football/team/_/id/52"
> for url in urls:

You're going through the characters of "urls", change it to a list:

```py
urls = ["https://www.espn.com/college-football/team/_/id/52"]
...
...
```

Also you don't have "parse_front" function, if you just didn't add it to the snippet then ignore this, if it was a mistake then change it to:

```py
yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: No problem, I would appreciate it if you accept my answer.